# How to setup gradle distZip task to put resources into sub-directories and classpath correctly?

Tags: java, gradle, build, classpath, build.gradle

I have these build.gradle files:

```
dependencies {
  runtime files('src/main/resources')
  runtime files('src/main/resources/cfg')
  runtime files('src/main/resources/sql')
}

jar {
  exclude 'cfg/*'
  exclude 'cfg/'
  exclude 'sql/*'
  exclude 'sql/'
}
```

And this one

```
dependencies {
  runtime files('src/main/resources')
  runtime files('src/main/resources/cfg')
  runtime files('src/main/resources/fxml')
  runtime files('src/main/resources/icons')
}

jar {
  exclude 'cfg/*'
  exclude 'cfg/'
  exclude 'icons/*'
  exclude 'icons/'
  exclude 'fxml/*'
  exclude 'fxml/'
}

startScripts {
  doLast {
    def winScriptFile = file getWindowsScript()
    def winFileText = winScriptFile.text
    winFileText = winFileText.replaceAll 'set CLASSPATH=.*', 'set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\\\\lib\\\\\\*;%APP_HOME%\\\\lib\\\\cfg;%APP_HOME%\\\\lib\\\\fxml;%APP_HOME%\\\\lib\\\\icons;%APP_HOME%\\\\lib\\\\sql'
  }
}
```

I can exclude the resource directories and their files from the projectName.jar file but I am not able to exclude the files from the sub-directories from the /lib directory which the distZip/distTar tasks create.

I want to have this layout in the zip/tar

```
projectName/
|
|-lib/
| |
| |-cfg/
| | |-*.*
| |     
| |-fxml/
| | |-*.fxml
| |
| |-icons/
| | |-*.ico
| |
| |-sql/
| | |-*.sql
| |
| |-*.jar
|
|-bin/
  |
  |-projectName.bat
```

Where all resources in the sub-directories are not included in the lib directory and the sub-directories are set in the `CLASSPATH` variable in the `projectName.bat` so that the application is able to load all resources.

Comment: Have you tried to use the gradle application plugin? It should pretty much provide all of the logic you need.

Comment: The distZip/distTar tasks are provided by the application plugin. I can't figure out how to configure it to achieve the desired result

Answer (score 2):

You could add a new source set that is not included in the project's JAR file:

```
sourceSets {
  dist {
    resources {
      srcDirs=['src/main/dist']
    }
  }
}
```

This source set contains the dependencies needed for the actual distribution. The folder structure under `src/main/dist` needs to rebuild the desired structure of the `distZip` artificat and will automatically be part of the ZIP/JAR:

```
src/main/dist
  └ lib
      ├ cfg
      │   └ …
      ├ sql
      ⁞   └ …
```

To add the resources to the application's classpath in the generated start script, you can to this:

```
startScripts.classpath.add(files('\"')).add(files('cfg')).add(files('sql'))
```

This will add `%APP_HOME%\lib\.`, `%APP_HOME%\lib\cfg` and `%APP_HOME%\lib\sql` to the classpath in your start script.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure it out, I had to give the resources like this which puts the sub-directories in the lib directory

```
dependencies {
  runtime files('src/main/resources')
}
```

and this change:

```
-    winFileText = winFileText.replaceAll 'set CLASSPATH=.*', 'set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\\\\lib\\\\\\*;%APP_HOME%\\\\lib\\\\cfg;%APP_HOME%\\\\lib\\\\fxml;%APP_HOME%\\\\lib\\\\icons;%APP_HOME%\\\\lib\\\\sql'
+    winFileText = winFileText.replaceAll 'set CLASSPATH=.*', 'set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\\\\lib\\\\\\*;%APP_HOME%\\\\lib;%APP_HOME%\\\\lib\\\\cfg;APP_HOME%\\\\lib\\\\fxml;APP_HOME%\\\\lib\\\\icons;APP_HOME%\\\\lib\\\\sql'
```

This was missing: `%APP_HOME%\\\\lib;`
It's needed because the fxml resources are referenced like this in the source code:

```
getClass().getResource("/fxml/somelayout.fxml")
```

It looks for the resource on the `CLASSPATH` in the `lib/` directory. This was missing.

Comment: Instead of replacing the whole classpath expression you could use `startScripts.classpath.add(files('\"'))` to add `%APP_HOME%\lib\.` to the classpath. This is probably more future proof regarding changes in the classpath.

Comment: ok, does that remove the autogenerated `CLASSPATH` variable?
I am using that because otherwise I ran into the "input line is too long" error on the commandline.

Comment: No I don't think so. But I could imagine that you can clear the classpath by `startScripts.classpath.clear()` and re-add the needed expressions. Or you could stick with your approach, if it's working... ;-)

Comment: looks like it uses [FileCollection](https://docs.gradle.org/current/groovydoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html) which does not have any method to remove/clear anything.